# "If this is too much for you"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request, idiomatic-language

> To track the changes and rollback them if necessary, use GitHub, Bitbucket, or GitLab. If you don’t know how to use Git, consider using a [GUI client](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows); **if this is too much either**, use a bunch of local timestamped copies and compare them using Meld or another comparison application.

I want to discourage beginner programmers ("students" for short) from using comments to track changes. Instead of using comments, I suggest them to use one of the three options:

- Git (for the most ambitious students)
- Git + GUI client over it (for students that are not that ambitious)
- Local copies + comparison application (for the least ambitious ones)

I'm not sure that **if this is too much either** is a correct way to show the jump from the second option to the third. I tried to find usage examples, and there are very few of them.

- Google: `"if this is too much either"` - only 2 real results, 0 trustworthy (e.g., from New York Times or some book).
- Google: `"if this is too much as well"` - 0 results.

And so I think this phrases are wrong. How to fix it? Or may be I should choose the completely different one?

Comment: I think your choice of words are perfect. The second option though sounds weird to me. I mean it is right, but doesn't fit into this context.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh _"The second option though sounds weird to me."_ - Which exactly phrase you mean?

Comment: I was taking about the second bulleted point at the ending of your question, "if this is too much as well"...that one.

Comment: In general, compound words that can be used as a noun or a verb  are written as one word when used as a noun and two words when used as a verb. For example: Please **set up** the software and configure it,  **Setup** and configuration should take no more than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a native speaker probably wouldn't say "rollback them". I would definitely say "roll them back" or "perform rollbacks".

**It does not make sense to use *either* here.** I would suggest taking that whole *if* phrase out and replacing it with **"Or, ...", "Otherwise, ..." or "Else, ..."**. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 1):

*Either* doesn't really fit - the way you're using it, you'd normally pair it with a negative phrase, like "if you don't know how to use this either...".

Personally I'd go with "if this is also too advanced" or "still too advanced", but something a little gentler like "if you're not comfortable with Git/this/these advanced tools" might be better, so they don't feel bad if they look at the Git manual pages and go pale :D